# Flutter. IOS signing issue. "Runner" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature

Tags: ios, flutter, signing

In my flutter project I'm using Codemagic as CI/CD tool.
After adding the flavor to the app, I started getting this error on one of the flavours.

```
> flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --build-name=0.0.1 --build-number=33 --flavor dev
Downloading ios tools...                                            2.4s
Downloading ios-profile tools...                                    1.5s
Downloading ios-release tools...                                    7.3s
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building se.getgaston.app for device (ios-release)...
Running pod install...                                            323.3s (!)
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           875.6s
Built /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.

> xcode-project build-ipa --workspace /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner.xcworkspace --scheme dev --config Release-dev
Archive Runner.xcworkspace
Execute "xcodebuild -workspace /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme dev -config Release-dev -archivePath build/ios/xcarchive/Runner_j1t8laki.xcarchive archive COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=28759WZ2NP 'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Distribution'"

❌  error: "Runner" requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

I've checked the certificate, provision profile and app id for both working flavour and one with signing issue and didn't find any difference.

Comment: Hi! How you found a solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by specifying bundle in iOS signing options

Comment: How please @Leo

Comment: How please @Leo 

Comment: In my case it was resolved by specifying Bundle identifier in Codemagic flow configuration, section Distribution, sub section iOS code signing

Answer (score 12):

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13065#issuecomment-357444789) helped me.

My command was `flutter build ipa --export-options-plist path/to/export.plist --build-number=123 --release --flavor=prod --dart-define=FLAVOR=prod`

Sample export.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>enterprise</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.company.appname</key>
        <string>provisioningProfiles name </string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>iOS Distribution</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>xxxxxx</string>
    <key>thinning</key>
    <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This didn't work...

Comment: This did work for me in the end, though since my team wasnt on apples enterprise dev plan, I had to change the "method" to `<string>app-store</string>`

Comment: Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For us, this was solved by adding a "Info.plist File" setting directly to all build schemes.

Before the change, the Info.plist was inherited from the Runner project:

[image: Screenshot showing the build configuration before changes]

To fix it, double-click on the top-level "Runner/info.plist":

[image: Screenshot showing open editor for Info.plist File]

Delete the text, and press return. This should clear the value for all projects.

Then, double-click in the same place, re-enter the same `Runner/info.plist` value again, and press return.

This should then update all the schemes to have the setting, rather than inheriting it.

The result should look like this:

[image: Screenshot showing the build configuration after changes]

This was caused by Codemagic's `xcode-project use-profiles` command. It expects each scheme to specify the Info.plist location, and doesn't parse inherited values.